# How do I get a table with 3 columns and the third colums only has 1<td> 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<html>
<body>
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 1000px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">Hanrathsingel 14</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage1_Home">Home</a></td>
            <td width="400" height="100%">This one has to take the full height of the table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">1252 AE Laren</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage2_Wie-zijn-wij">Wie zijn wij</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">T. 035-6231419</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage3_Informatie">Informatie</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">M. 06-21700357</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage9_Algemene-voorwaarden">Algemene Voorwaarden</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300"><a href="mailto:laren@qualitysites4all.com">laren@qualitysites4all.com</a></td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage4_Contact">Contact</a></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the column to be 100% of the table height but the other columns must keep their height?

Because I want to put a widget in there but I have to work in my boss his cms and I am not allowed to make new divs :(

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=don%27t+use+tables+for+layout

Comment: "columns must keep their height" - columns have no height, you mean width?

Comment: columns will take the table height by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [rowspan](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6.1):

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 1000px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">Hanrathsingel 14</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage1_Home">Home</a></td>
            <td width="400" rowspan="5">This one has to take the full height of the table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">1252 AE Laren</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage2_Wie-zijn-wij">Wie zijn wij</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">T. 035-6231419</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage3_Informatie">Informatie</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">M. 06-21700357</td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage9_Algemene-voorwaarden">Algemene Voorwaarden</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="300"><a href="mailto:laren@qualitysites4all.com">laren@qualitysites4all.com</a></td>
            <td width="300"><a href="cmsPage4_Contact">Contact</a></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rdCt7/)

Comment: thx dude you helped me out with my final project for school :D

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MVhZe/)

Use `rowspan="5"` in that TD.

Rowspan attribute, tells your element to "get the height" of 5 rows in this case.

If you have dinamic content remember to update this value to the actual number of rows of your table.